# Understanding sheet/cell referencing in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I moved a macro button with some pretty extensive coding so users won't accidently click it. Basically, the macro sends information on sheet one to a summary workbook. I thought that I could just move the button since the first part of the code that looks for the variables needed selects the worksheet I actually want to get information from. However the macro still looks at the activeworksheet to get the variables. I can fix this by simply putting the worksheet reference along with the range reference to get the necessary information, but I didn't think I needed to do that. Is there a way to only reference the sheet once so the code looks for all information on the worksheet I need information from?

first code--gets information from whatever worksheet it's attached to, in this case sheet2:

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    AgentName = Range("C2")
    'Set IncidentReport = Range("d1:f1")
    County = Range("d1")
    Idate = Format(Range("e1"), "yyyymmdd")
    LogNum = Format(Range("f1"), "000")
    IncidentReport = County & Idate & LogNum
```

This code pulls the information from the correct sheet, but I have a lot of variables I'm looking to get and surely there is a better way:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    AgentName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
    'Set IncidentReport = Range("d1:f1")
    County = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d1")
    Idate = Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("e1"), "yyyymmdd")
    LogNum = Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("f1"), "000")
    IncidentReport = County & Idate & LogNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a With statement - note the dots in front of the ranges. However, your first code should work I'd have thought - do you have more than one workbook in operation?

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    AgentName = .Range("C2")
    County = .Range("d1")
    Idate = Format(.Range("e1"), "yyyymmdd")
    LogNum = Format(.Range("f1"), "000")
    IncidentReport = County & Idate & LogNum
end with
```

Comment: I guess I do. When I click the button, the code looks at one workbook to get information and then opens another workbook to insert the information in the next empty row.

Comment: You need to add workbook references in the same way as sheet references. Please accept the/an answer if it's answered your question.

Comment: Referencing the workbook didn't work. The only thing that worked was adding the worksheet reference along with every cell reference. I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing, but the above changes you recommended did not allow the code to run.

Comment: We've both answered the question you asked. The workbook issue is a separate question and you haven't provided enough information for that to be answered. The point of With is that you don't need to specify the sheet each time.

Comment: I understand the point of with but that didn't work. When I added it with the way you instructed, I got an error saying the object was required. I didn't think I had an issue with workbook references and didn't receive and error in that regard. I was simply answering your question regarding it. It's my understanding that I accept answers that work, is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm not asking you to accept an answer which didn't work, and I'm not that fussed anyway, but your question was "Is there a way to only reference the sheet once so the code looks for all information on the worksheet I need information from?" and as I say we have both answered that. Perhaps you need to ask another question.

Comment: So are you saying I should accept this answer because it should have answered the question we thought I was asking? Or just answers should be accepted because you attempted? It doesn't matter if the answer is corrected the issue? Not trying to be obtuse. I'll go back and read the policies concerning this. I certainly want to give credit where it is do.

Comment: Looking at your profile, you appear to have a problem acknowledging the help you receive in general.

Comment: Yes, I have apparently misunderstood the conditions I am supposed to accept answers. I am looking some clarification on how to correct this.

Comment: This is my final word. The main thing is that you get the answers you need and that those helping have their contributions acknowledged (at least an expression of gratitude, although the system is points-based). If you are not getting the answers you need, perhaps revisit how you couch your questions. If you are and have just not understood how the system works that is easily fixed.

Comment: In reading some of the questions about accepting the answer, it appears that answers that correct the problem should be accepted. Neither did which is why they are not accepted. I don't think I failed to ask the correct question. Workbook referencing was never a problem and even when I added that, the error remained. As you see, I am new to this site and my upvotes do not show up since my reputation is so low. I upvoted your answer and appreciate your help, but it did not correct the issue I was having.

Comment: Final final word! You haven't upvoted either answer, perhaps you have not got to grips with the system. Try reading [ask] if you haven't already. I suggest you then ask a new question rather than prolong this one.

Comment: I did upvote your answer. When I upvote, I get a note saying that the upvote is recorded but because my reputation is not 15, it doesn't change the public score. Idk if you can see my upvote otherwise. This initial issue has been corrected but not by using the methods you recommended. There is no need to ask another question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `with` block:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    AgentName = .Range("C2")
    'Set IncidentReport = Range("d1:f1")
    County = .Range("d1")
    Idate = Format(.Range("e1"), "yyyymmdd")
    LogNum = Format(.Range("f1"), "000")
    IncidentReport = County & Idate & LogNum
End With
```

Within the `with` block, you can reference your object using `.` so `object.a` becomes `.`

Comment: When I tried that, and use ".Range("C2"), I get an error saying an object is required. I tried referencing the workbook with ThisWorkbook too. If I remove the '.' then the code works, but references sheet2 and not sheet1.